# XAMPP 1.7.4 on Windows 7 Defaults to Splash page

Tags: windows, xampp, virtualhost

I set up XAMPP running apache and tried to set up the virtual host, but it wouldn't work, I keep getting routed to the XAMPP splash page. `http://localhost/index.html` says "It works!"
I uncommented the are where it said vhost_alias module, httpd-vhosts and rewrite_module.

I also added the following to my httpd-vhosts.conf & httpd.conf files:

```
<Directory "C:/Sites/test.dev-web">
Allow From All
AllowOverride FileInfo
Options +FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName "test.dev-web"
        DocumentRoot "C:/Sites/test.dev-web"
</VirtualHost>
```

I also added this to my hosts file in my system32\drivers\etc:

```
127.0.0.1     test.dev
```

I also have `127.0.0.1 localhost` in that file

However whenever I type in test.dev in chrome, it takes me to the xampp splash page (test.dev/xampp).

Running windows 7 and XAMPP 1.7.4

XAMPP says that apache is running on the control panel.
I shut off all programs that could be running port 80 (skype)

Any ideas on what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the step mentioned here -

http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/apache22_vhosts.php

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution: Delete XAMPP's local test site (xampp/htdocs) and replace it with your own site.

The Correct solution: Set up proper virtual hosts. [Set up multiple virtual hosts on windows](http://ailoo.net/2008/07/set-up-multiple-virtual-hosts-on-xampp-for-windows/)

or the link that Vinay shared will give you a good guide.